# ConstraintLayout not returning any output in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to do a constraint layout in my Compose view.  Unfortunately, I get no output.  I was having problems using columns to show error output after the TextField, so in desperation, I am using a constraint layout.  Here is the component:

```
@Composable
fun StateAndZip(
    modifier: Modifier,
    onFormChanged: (FormType, String) -> Unit,
    selectedLocation: Address,
    stateError: Boolean,
    zipError: Boolean
) {
ConstraintLayout  {
    val (stateDropDown, shippingField) = createRefs()
    StateSelection(
        modifier = modifier.constrainAs(stateDropDown) {
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
            end.linkTo(shippingField.start, margin = 8.dp)
            width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent
            height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
        },
        onFormChanged = onFormChanged,
        selectedLocation = selectedLocation,
        label = "State",
        error = stateError,
    )
    ShippingField(
        modifier = modifier.constrainAs(shippingField) {
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
            width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent
            height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
        },
        onFormChanged = onFormChanged,
        formType = FormType.SHIPPING_ZIP,
        label = "Zip",
        valueField = selectedLocation.zipCode,
        error = zipError
    )
   }
}
```

Here is where I'm calling it:

```
@Composable
fun ShippingForm(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onFormChanged: (FormType, String) -> Unit,
    selectedLocation: Address,
    validateErrors: Boolean
) {

var cityError by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
var stateError by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
var countryError by remember {mutableStateOf(false)}
var zipError by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

if (validateErrors) {
    if (selectedLocation.shippingCity.isBlank()) {
        cityError = true
    }
    if (selectedLocation.shippingState.isBlank()) {
        stateError = true

    }
    if (selectedLocation.zipCode.isBlank()) {
        zipError = true

    }
    if (selectedLocation.shippingCountry.isBlank()) {
        countryError = true
    }
}

//already in a column, so no need to add another one.

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(spacerHeight()))
    ShippingField(
        modifier = modifier,
        onFormChanged = onFormChanged,
        formType = FormType.SHIPPING_2,
        label = "Apartment, suite, etc. (Optional)",
        valueField = selectedLocation.shipping2,
        error = false
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(spacerHeight()))
    ShippingField(
        modifier = modifier,
        onFormChanged = onFormChanged,
        formType = FormType.SHIPPING_CITY,
        label = "City",
        valueField = selectedLocation.shippingCity,
        error = cityError
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(spacerHeight()))
    StateAndZip(
        modifier = modifier,
        onFormChanged = onFormChanged,
        selectedLocation = selectedLocation,
        stateError = stateError,
        zipError = zipError
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(spacerHeight()))
    CountrySelection(
        onFormChanged = onFormChanged,
        selectedLocation = selectedLocation,
        label = "Country",
        error = countryError
    )


}
```

The individual views are quite complex.  Here is the stateDropDown:

```
@Composable
fun StateSelection(
    modifier: Modifier,
    onFormChanged: (FormType, String) -> Unit,
    selectedLocation: Address,
    error: Boolean,
    label: String
) {
// State variables
val statesMap = AddressUtils.mapOfAmericanStatesToValue
var stateName: String by remember { mutableStateOf(selectedLocation.shippingState) }
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
var errorState by remember { mutableStateOf(error)}


    // Create references for the composables to constrain
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Row(
            Modifier
                .clickable {
                    expanded = !expanded
                },
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) { // Anchor view
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                value = stateName,
                onValueChange = {
                    onFormChanged(FormType.SHIPPING_COUNTRY, it)
                },
                label = { Text(text = label) },
                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
                singleLine = true,
                trailingIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { expanded = true }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown,
                            contentDescription = "",
                            tint = if (errorState) MaterialTheme.colors.error
                            else MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary
                        )
                    }
                },
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = {
                    focusManager.moveFocus(
                        FocusDirection.Down
                    )
                }),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
                ),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                    textColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
                    focusedLabelColor = if (errorState) MaterialTheme.colors.error
                    else MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = if (errorState) MaterialTheme.colors.error
                    else MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryVariant
                )
            ) // state name label
            DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false
            }) {
                statesMap.asIterable().iterator().forEach {
                    val (key, value) = it
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        onClick = {
                            expanded = false
                            stateName = key
                            onFormChanged(FormType.SHIPPING_STATE, key)
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {
                        Text(text = key)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (errorState && error) {
        ErrorMessages(modifier = modifier, message = "$label is required")
    }
}
```

[image: no views on Compose]

Comment: I won't advise on it since I never use `ConstraintLayout`, but I'd definitely recommend that you use the `Layout` Composable for positioning instead. It's highly reliable, gets the job done, is intuitive once you get the basics down, and using it is super-easy, barely an inconvenience.